# Como colocar máscara de peso em input usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Até agora estou tentando assim, mas não deu certo:

```
$('.peso').keyup(function () {
var v = this.value,
integer = v.split('.')[0];

v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");

v = v.replace(/^[0]+/, "");

if (v.length <= 3 || !integer) {

if (v.length === 1) v = '0.00' + v;

if (v.length === 2) v = '0.0' + v;

if (v.length === 3) v = '0.' + v;
} else { v = v.replace(/^(\d{1,})(\d{3})$/, "$1.$2");}
this.value = v;});
```

HTML:

```
<p><label>Capacacidade</label></p>
<div class="input-group has-success">
<input type="text" name="txtcapac" placeholder="Capacidade em Kg" class="peso form-control"/>
<div class="input-group-addon"><span>Kg</span></div>
```

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o jquery.mask?

Comment: Esse?function mascara(t, mask){
 var i = t.value.length;
 var saida = mask.substring(1,0);
 var texto = mask.substring(i)
 if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
 t.value += texto.substring(0,1);
 }
 }

Comment: O [plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) mesmo, vou postar um exemplo como resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o plugin jQuery Mask - http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.weight').mask("#0.000", {reverse: true});
})
```

Comment: Ainda não deu certo, acho que estou fazendo alguma coisa errada. <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.peso').mask("#0.000", {reverse: true});
})
</script>

Comment: é só isso mesmo?

Comment: Você poderia verificar no console do browser se esta aparecendo algum erro?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
cadastro_equipamento.html:44 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function

Comment: Você adicionou o script do jquery.mask no seu código?

Comment: pois é não adicionei, a única coisa que adicionei foi o código que digitei antes

Comment: mas como faço isso? sou bem leiga em javascript

Comment: Basta você [baixar o plugin no github](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/master/dist/jquery.mask.min.js) e depois adicionar a pasta do seu projeto e linkar com a tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="localdoscript"></script>`

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda e paciência, tá funcionado direitinho agora. vlw

Answer (score -2):

Estou conseguindo...valeu amigo!
galera ficou show...

$('.peso').keyup(function () {
var v = this.value,
integer = v.split('.')[0];

```
v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");

v = v.replace(/^[0]+/, "");

if (v.length <= 5 || !integer) {

    if (v.length === 5) v =  v.substring(0,2) + '.' + v.substring(2,5) ;

    if (v.length === 4) v = '0' + v.substring(0,1) + '.' + v.substring(1,4) ;

    if (v.length === 3) v = '00.' + v;
    
    if (v.length === 2) v = '00.0' + v;
    
    if (v.length === 1) v = '00.00' + v;
    
} else {
    //  v = v.replace(/^(\d{2,})(\d{3})$/, "$1.$2");
    if (v.length > 5 || !integer) {
        v =  v.substring(0,2) + '.' + v.substring(2,5) ;
    }
}
select.value = v;
```

### });

no html....

Peso Bolsa(kg)